# /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory error when running on ubuntu docker image and macbook m1 host

Tags: linux, docker, go

I'm building a golang application that as part of it's work it builds a chroot jail environment for the user, one of the file that need to be copied to the jailed environment is `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`
When the app is running on a ubuntu:22.04 docker container, the copy fails with error `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory`
The app is intended to run on ubuntu, but I'm developing on apple m1.
When I build the image with build option `--platform linux/amd64` everything works, but there are two issues with this approach:

- `delve` debugger not working: https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/3616, so using this flag I can't debug on the docker container itself, which is critical for this kind of development.
- when using this flag the build time is 20x slower.

the docker file:

```
# Compile stage
FROM golang:1.21 AS build-env

RUN go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest

ADD . /dockerdev
WORKDIR /dockerdev

RUN go build -gcflags="all=-N -l" -o /server

# Final stage
FROM ubuntu:22.04

WORKDIR /
COPY --from=build-env /go/bin/dlv /
COPY --from=build-env /server /

EXPOSE 8000 40000

CMD ["/dlv", "--listen=:40000", "--headless=true", "--api-version=2", "--accept-multiclient", "exec", "/server"]
```

I'm using intellij to debug the app inside the container: https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2020/05/06/debugging-a-go-application-inside-a-docker-container/

Any ideas for a workaround?